# VS Intellisense: removing some autocomplete words

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I like that the intellisense in VS corrects me when I make mistakes, but sometimes I don't make any mistakes and it corrects me still. I'm coding for Unity and I cannot write "var" without it being changed to "SerializePrivateVariables" as soon as I press space.

Is there a way to remove some of the autocomplete triggers in the intellisense? I couldn't find how to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot disable specific words from autocompletion in C# in Visual Studio 2015 as far as I know.

In your case, however, you can enable keywords in completion lists. Then the intellisense should understand that `var` is a proper C# and not replace it.

You can do this by going to TOOLS > Options > Text Editor > C# > Intellisense and checking the "Place keywords in completion lists" option.

There is a bit more options in VS2017 and VS2013 (and older), but none of them have the exact feature you have in mind.

Comment: I see, thank you, it's working! 
Got another little qwirk with the IntelliSense, if you don't mind:
there are some things I often write and the IntelliSense result don't make sense to me: http://i.imgur.com/Zx1DYmQ.png

I'm writing Update and I'm hoping to get the Update() method come up but instead it's the AnimatorUpdateMode that comes up instead as a 1st choice.
I thought choosing the Update option several times might make it understand that it's my favorite choice but it doesn't change.

Is there some way to prioritize the Update() method to be the 1st choice?

Comment: @Feast There was an option to enable/disable automatic pre-selection of most often used entry in VS2013, but it is no longer present in newer versions. VS2015 seems to be completely missing this feature while VS2017 automatically pre-selects last used entry. So perhaps you can consider upgrading. Another option could be using external tool (like Resharper) to improve your experience.